# OpenGL matrix setup for tiled rendering

Tags: opengl, matrix, tile

After reading [datenwolf's 2011 answer concerning tile-based render setup in OpenGL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6490728/capture-snapshot-of-opengl-window-with-very-large-image-resolution), I attempted to implement his solution.  The source image looks like this (at 800 x 600)

[image: Original image]

The resulting image with 2x2 tiles, each tile at 800 x 600 per tile looks like this.

[image: Resulting 4 images joined together]

As you can see they don't exactly match, though I can see something vaguely interesting has happened.  I'm sure I've made an elementary error somewhere but I can't quite see it.

I'm doing 4 passes where:

```
w, h are 2,2 (2x2 tiles)    
x, y are (0,0) (1,0) (0,1) and (1,1) in each of the 4 passes    
MyFov is 1.30899692 (75 degrees)
MyWindowWidth, MyWindowHeight are 800, 600
MyNearPlane, MyFarPlane are 0.1, 200.0
```

The algorithm to calculate the frustum for each tile is:

```
auto aspect = static_cast<float>(MyWindowWidth) / static_cast<float>(MyWindowHeight);
auto right = -0.5f * Math::Tan(MyFov) * MyShaderData.Camera_NearPlane;
auto left = -right;
auto top = aspect * right;
auto bottom = -top;
auto shift_X = (right - left) / static_cast<float>(w);
auto shift_Y = (top - bottom) / static_cast<float>(h);
auto frustum = Math::Frustum(left   + shift_X * static_cast<float>(x),
                             left   + shift_X * static_cast<float>(x + 1), 
                             bottom + shift_Y * static_cast<float>(y),
                             bottom + shift_Y * static_cast<float>(y + 1),
                             MyShaderData.Camera_NearPlane,
                             MyShaderData.Camera_FarPlane);
```

, where Math::Frustum is:

```
template<class T>
Matrix4x4<T> Frustum(T left, T right, T bottom, T top, T nearPlane, T farPlane)
{
    Matrix4x4<T> r(InitialiseAs::InitialiseZero);

    r.m11 = (static_cast<T>(2) * nearPlane) / (right - left);
    r.m22 = (static_cast<T>(2) * nearPlane) / (top - bottom);
    r.m31 = (right + left) / (right - left);
    r.m32 = (top + bottom) / (top - bottom);
    r.m33 = -(farPlane + nearPlane) / (farPlane - nearPlane);
    r.m34 =   static_cast<T>(-1);
    r.m43 = -(static_cast<T>(2) * farPlane * nearPlane) / (farPlane - nearPlane);

    return r;
}
```

For completeness, my Matrx4x4 layout is:

```
struct
{
    T m11, m12, m13, m14;
    T m21, m22, m23, m24;
    T m31, m32, m33, m34;
    T m41, m42, m43, m44;
};
```

Can anyone spot my error?

**Edit**:

So derhass explained it to me - a much easier way of doing things is to simply scale and translate the projection matrix.  For testing I modified my translation matrix, scaled up by 2x, as follows (changing translate for each tile):

```
auto scale = Math::Scale(2.f, 2.f, 1.f);
auto translate = Math::Translate(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.f);
auto projection = Math::Perspective(MyFov,
                                    static_cast<float>(MyWindowWidth) / static_cast<float>(MyWindowHeight),
                                    MyShaderData.Camera_NearPlane,
                                    MyShaderData.Camera_FarPlane);          

MyShaderData.Camera_Projection = scale * translate * projection;
```

The resulting image is below (stitching 4 together) - the discontinuities in the image are caused by the post processing I think, so that's another issue I might have to deal with at some point.

[image: Resulting image]

Comment: I haven't checked what is wrong in your implementation, but I think that  datenwolf's solution there is unnecessary complex. If you have render some scene with some projection matrix (no matter if ortho or perspective), the resulting frustum will end up in the homogenous representation of the [-1,1]^3 NDC space. So if you want some tile of that rendered full-screen, it is suffcient to just _pre-multiply_ some scale and translation in x and y to select any 2D sub-rectangle you like (which will have the same effect as changing FOV and asymmetry in a perspective frustum).

Comment: I thought NDC happened after homogenous divide, which is after multiplication by projection matrix, so I don't see how that will work.  Regardless I tried with WxH scale premultiply and various different translations and I couldn't get it to work.  The math is wrong.

Comment: What I propose is applied in clip space. I only braught NDC in for the [-1,1] range of the frustum. The key point is that applying a simple translate and scale after applying the projection matrix (which means _pre_ multiplying it following the default GL conventions) to scale and shift some sub-rectangle of [-1,1] to the full [-1,1] range will exactly get you that part of the image in the full viewport.

Comment: E.g, if you want the top-left quater of the image which you would get by applying matrix `P`, you can simply use `P' = S(2,2,1) * T(0.5, -0.5, 0) * P` (with `S` being a scale matrix and `T` a translation) as a replacement for `P` (no matter what kind of projection P is, it will work in any case). All of this assumes you use GL's usual matrix conventions, so that the transformation of a vertex `v` is `v'=M * v`. If you use `v' = M *v`, post-multiplying the modifications is the correct way.

Comment: Ah, only took me 2 days to "get it".  Please add this as the answer so I can give you some points.  I'll edit my question to show the result.

Comment: Actually still having trouble understanding things.  I see the scale is n, m, where n and m are the number of tiles on x and y.  I don't see how the translation is found, given NDC space is -1, 1 (i.e. it's 2 wide, not 1).  I manually made 4 renders at (.5, .5) , (.5, -.5), (-.5, .5), (-.5, -.5) for the 4 quadrants in a 2x2 tile system.  I don't see how to generalise that to n, m tiles however.

Comment: I wrote an answer, hopefully explaning all what is still unclear to you. Maybe what confuses you is that the order of transformations is _backwards_.  What confuses me is your result screenshot: What kind of postprocessing are you doing, so that those discontinuities arise? From the tiled rendering alone, the images should match 100%.

Comment: I'm extracting the bright bits of the image, blurring them (Gaussian) and then blending the blur on top for the final result.  Result should be subtle glow of specular, though it's not completely obvious in that screenshot.

Comment: I also just tried it without post processing and the discontinuities are still there, so I have no clue at this point what's causing it.

Comment: Final comment on this:  The discontinuity disappears when I just save the RGB contents of the texture to disk, loading it into paintshop pro as RAW.  The image is much darker as well due to the fact paintshop doesn't gamma correct it, whereas the hardware does for display (my pipeline is SRGB).  So whatever's going on here is to do with the conversion process/windows desktop, which I was previously screenshotting and joining, rather than saving directly from code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't a real answer for the question, but it might be an useful alternative approach to what you are trying to solve here. In my opinion, datenwolf's solution in his answer to the [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6490728/capture-snapshot-of-opengl-window-with-very-large-image-resolution) you are referring to is more comlicated that it needs to be. So I'm presenting my alternative here.

Forword: I assume standard OpenGL matrix conventions, so that the vertex transformation with matrix `M` is done as `v'= M *v` (like the fixed-function pipeline did).

When a scene is rendered with some projection matrix `P`, you can extract any axis-aligned sub-rectangle of said scene by applying a scale and transformation operation *after* the projection matrix is applied.

The key point is that the viewing volume is defined as the [-1,1]^3 cube in NDC space. The clip space (which is what `P` transforms the data to) is just the homogenous represenation of that volume. As the typical `4x4` transformation matrices are all working in homogenous space, we don't really need to care about `w` at all and simply can define the transformations as if we were in NDC space.

Since you only need some 2D tiling, `z` should be left as-is, and only some scale and translation in `x` and `y` is required. When composing transformations `A` and `B` into a single Matrix `C` as `C=A*B`, following the aforementioned conventions this results in `B` being applied first, and `A` last (since `C*v == A*B*v == A*(B*v)`). So to modify the result *after* projection, we have to *pre*-multiply some transformations to `P` and we are done:

```
P'=S(sx,sy,1) * T(tx,ty,0) * P
```

The construction of `P'` will work with any valid projection matrix `P`, no matter if it is a perspective or ortho transform. In the ortho case, what this does is quite clear. In the perspective case, this actually modifies both the field of view and also shifts the frustum to an asymmetric one.

When you want to tile the image into a grid of `m` times `n` segments. it is clear that `sx=m` and `sy=n`. As I did use the `S * T` order (by choice), `T` is applied before the scale, so for each tile, `(tx,ty)` is just the vector moving the center of the tile to the new center (which will be the origin). As NDC space is 2 units wide and tall, for a tile `x,y`, the transformation is

```
tx= - (-1 + 2/(2*m) + (2/m) * x)
ty= - (-1 + 2/(2*n) + (2/n) * y)
//     ^     ^         ^    
//     |     |         |
//     |     |         +- size of of each tile in NDC space
//     |     |
//     |     +- half the size (as the center offset)
//     |
//     +- left/bottom border of NDC space
```

Comment: by the way, if you are using extra clippingplanes, this solution will not work correctly.

Comment: @Thomas: that depends on how you apply the extra clip planes. Usually, they are defined in world or eye space, which is not modified at all by this approach.