# WebGL maximum resolution? gl.readPixels returning empty pixels

Tags: javascript, node.js, webgl

I'm using [headless-gl](https://github.com/stackgl/headless-gl) together with node to render a high-res generated WebGL image on the server-side. This works fine depending on the chosen resolution.

```js
'use strict';

const Gl = require('gl');
const width   = 7200;
const height  = 10800;

// Setup renderer using headless-gl
const gl = Gl(width, height, { preserveDrawingBuffer: true })

// Clear screen to red
gl.clearColor(1, 0, 0, 1)
gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)

// Get pixels
const pixels = new Uint8Array(width * height * 4);
gl.readPixels(0, 0, width, height, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);

// Is first color indeed red?
if (pixels[0] === 255) {
   console.log('OK'); 
}

process.exit();
```

After some point of increasing the width/height values the `pixels` array is filled with only zero values for the rgba pixels. I'm guessing that I'm hitting a memory/buffer limit somewhere but I'm not sure which one. According to nvidia-smi the GPU memory (12GB) is nowhere near depletion when running this.

What is the theoretical maximum resolution for webgl and what is it dependent on?

Comment: You might want to also check for errors by calling `gl.getError()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a maximum viewport size, that is independent of the amount of GPU memory.

You can see the limits using `gl.getParameter`:

```
console.log(gl.getParameter(gl.MAX_VIEWPORT_DIMS))
console.log(gl.getParameter(gl.MAX_RENDERBUFFER_SIZE))
```

My guess is that you're hitting the `MAX_VIEWPORT_DIMS` limitation.

Comment: Thanks that is helpful!

Comment: Capture snapshot of OpenGL window with very large image resolution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6491939/243103

Comment: That answer @stefan referenced is for OpenGL. While the idea is sound the actual solution has nothing to do with WebGL. WebGL doesn't have those functions. If you're using three.js [you can reference this sample](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_multiple_canvases_grid.html). Otherwise the solution of rendering a grid of images to make a larger image will depend on your shaders and your chosen math library.